# How do I specify variables for reusable parameters for Vertices in `tikz-network`?

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to specify the parameters once and then apply them to a large number of `\Vertex` nodes.

I.e. for regular tikz nodes you can use `\tikzstyle` for repeating parameters for nodes. Also I  want to set the parameters for `\Vertex` and not the underlying `\node`.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-network}
\tikzstyle{my_tikz_style}=[fill=green]
\tikzstyle{my_network_style}=[Math]
\tikzstyle{my_network_style_wrong}=[fill=red]
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my_tikz_style] (A) at (0,1){};
  \Vertex[Math,y=2]{B}
  % what works, but what I don't want: 
  \Vertex[y=3,style=my_network_style_wrong]{C}
  
  % what i want, but doesn't work: 
  %\Vertex[my_network_style,y=4]{D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I haven't found any way to do this in [tikz network documentation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06005.pdf).

If you can name decent alternative to the package `tikz-network`, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the package documentation, it seems there is the possibility to set the style for all the `\Vertex` but not to create a style to use for some of them containing the boolean `Math`.

Try with a new command.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}% tikz-network already loads TikZ
\usepackage{tikz-network}
% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles
\tikzset{
    my_tikz_style/.style={fill=green},
    my_network_style_wrong/.style={fill=red}
    }
\newcommand{\mynetworkstyle}{Math}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[my_tikz_style] (A) at (0,1){};
  \Vertex[Math,y=2]{B}
  % what works, but what I don't want: 
  \Vertex[y=3,style=my_network_style_wrong]{C}
  
  % what you want: 
  \Vertex[\mynetworkstyle,y=4]{D}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have forgotten what I needed this for, but I think your solution would answer my question exactly, so thanks.

Comment: @wotanii I'm searching for old unanswered questions :D Thank you for accepting!